# how to connect to the database in openshift application

Tags: php, pdo, cloud, openshift

I did as following

MySQL 5.1 database added. Please make note of these credentials:

```
    Root User: xxxxxxx
    Root Password: xxxxxxx
    Database Name: php


 Connection URL: mysql://$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST:$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT/
```

You can manage your new MySQL database by also embedding phpmyadmin-3.4.
    The phpmyadmin username and password will be the same as the MySQL credentials above.

phpMyAdmin 3.4 added. Please make note of these MySQL credentials again:

```
    Root User: xxxxxxx
    Root Password: xxxxxxx

    URL: https://php-doers.rhcloud.com/phpmyadmin/
```

and i try to connect db using bellow PDO code .but it does not work

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=mysql://$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST:$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT/;dbname=php', "xxxxxx, "xxxxxx");
```

I don't know what is the connection URL mean ?

Answer (score 19):

There is an error in your connection string plus $OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_* are env variables and need to be fetched via getenv php function.

So try the following:

```
define('DB_HOST', getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST'));
define('DB_PORT',getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT')); 
define('DB_USER',getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME'));
define('DB_PASS',getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD'));
define('DB_NAME',getenv('OPENSHIFT_GEAR_NAME'));

$dsn = 'mysql:dbname='.DB_NAME.';host='.DB_HOST.';port='.DB_PORT;
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
```

Answer (score 3):

Open php myadmin from webconsole , and on left corner you will get some Ip

That is like xx.xx.xx.xx:3306 , so your hostname is xx.xx.xx.xx

Ip address wil work , I have tried and worked for me

Comment: You can just ıse this as env variable: OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST, such as `echo $OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST` in terminal or `getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST')` in PHP files etc.

Answer (score 2):

below code worked for me ,try this it might help you

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var mysql = require('mysql');
exports.pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: process.env.OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST || 'localhost',
      port: process.env.OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT || '3306',
      user: process.env.OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME || 'root',
      password: process.env.OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD ||  '',
      database: 'chichat' || 'chichat',
      multipleStatements : true,
      charset: 'utf8'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add some information to future reference.
Today I am trying to deploy a Drupal installation to Open Shift (OS) and tried to configure MySql. 
I connected to OS via SSH (rhc ssh ), went to app-root/data/sites/default. Following cat settings.php to see how OS configure database.
Here it is:

```
// When run from Drush, only $_ENV is available.  Might be a bug
if (array_key_exists('OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME', $_SERVER)) {
  $src = $_SERVER;
} else {
  $src = $_ENV;
}
$databases = array (
  'default' => 
  array (
    'default' => 
    array (
      'database' => $src['OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME'],
      'username' => $src['OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME'],
      'password' => $src['OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD'],
      'host' => $src['OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST'],
      'port' => $src['OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT'],
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ),
  ),
);
$conf['file_private_path'] = $src['OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR'] . 'private/';
$conf['file_temporary_path'] = $src['OPENSHIFT_TMP_DIR'] . 'drupal/';
```

So I created a php folder into git repository (see OS documentation about Drupal), copied a clean Drupal install to it and paste code above to settings.php.
After pushing to git, restarted OS app and worked!