# MySQL / CodeIgniter configuration on OpenShift

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, openshift

I've deployed a PHP/CodeIgniter app to my OpenShift gear, but I'm getting an error

*Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
Filename: core/Loader.php
Line Number: 346*

After reading around, I'm guessing this is a problem of setting up my database configuration in CodeIgniters config/database.php

I've picked up that Openshift advises using environment variables rather than ip addresses, I've retrieved my details through SSH > grep|env and I've tried various ways of putting them in, without success.

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = $_ENV['OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST'];
$db['default']['username'] = '...'; //proper username
$db['default']['password'] = '...'; // proper password
$db['default']['database'] = 'products';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';

etc...
```

So my question is this: Where can I find a sample of an OpenShift config/database.php file as used in a PHP/CodeIgniter app?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15921169/how-to-connect-to-the-database-in-openshift-application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try restarting your application to see if just isn't picking up the environment variables.

rhc app restart