# openshift scaled app with port forward - Unable to access mysql on localhost

Tags: mysql, openshift

openshift scaled app with port forward - Unable to access mysql on localhost.

I have a simple php scaled app, I was able to setup the port forwarding for myapp. I can see that the 127.0.0.1:37731 is pointing to the openshift mysql gear.

But when I try to access mysql on command line or using mysql workbench, I am getting a 
"Connected to MySQL at 127.0.0.1:37731 with user adminXXXXX", connection parameters are incorrect error.

I am ubuntu. "adminXXXXX:@127.0.0.1:37731:" is the connection string when I copy it from the workbench.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15921169/how-to-connect-to-the-database-in-openshift-application

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying the host separately.

E.g. after port forwarding, I entered

```
mysql --host=127.0.0.1:40793
```

and got

```
ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host '127.0.0.1:40793'
```

but this worked:

```
mysql --host=127.0.0.1 --port=40793
```