# MySQL Database connection for OpenShift 2

Tags: mysql, openshift, openshift-cartridge

I have 2 cartridges in OpenShift 2, one for Tomcat 7 where my war is deployed and the other is a MySQL cartridge where I am hosting my DB. This is my context.xml file

```
<Context>
<Resource
  name="jdbc/src"
  type="javax.sql.DataSource"
  maxActive="4"
  maxIdle="2"
  username="admin****I"
  maxWait="5000"
  validationQuery="select 1"         
  driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
  password="########"     
  url="jdbc:mysql://pi-******.rhcloud.com:3306/pi"/>

</Context>
```

My URL where I access the application is pi-******.rhcloud.com and my DB name in MySQL cartridge is pi, so is my context.xml correct? Is this how I connect to the DB from a war deployed on OpenShift?

Comment: You may try adding phpmyadmin cartridge to openshift, for a GUI based interface to database

Comment: I don't really need a GUI for my DB, I just need to be able to connect to the DB from my war file. I want to know if my connection details are correct.

Comment: I think you need to use Openshift constants and it will automatically set up the proper values there

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15921169/how-to-connect-to-the-database-in-openshift-application

Comment: https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/adding-a-database.html